# Searching for a string on multiple zip files

Tags: grep, solaris, search, zip

I am working on SunOS 5.10. I have a folder that contains about 200 zip files. Each zip file contains only one text file in it. 
I would like to search for a specific string in all the text files in all the zip files.

I tried this (which searches for any text file in the zip file that contains the string "ORA-")  but it didn't work.

```
zipgrep ORA-1680 *.zip
```

What is the correct of doing it without uncompressing the zip files?

Comment: See also [How do I recursively grep through compressed archives?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13749) (not an exact duplicate, because the requirements there were more complicated).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is in general not possible to search for content within a compressed file without uncompressing it one way or another.
Since zipgrep is only a shellscript, wrapping unzip and egrep itself, you might just as well do it manually:

```
for file in *.zip; do unzip -c "$file" | grep "ORA-1680"; done
```

If you need just the list of matching zip files, you can use something like:

```
for file in *.zip; do
    if ( unzip -c "$file" | grep -q "ORA-1680"); then
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```

This way you are only decompressing to stdout (ie. to memory) instead of decompressing the files to disk. You can of course try to just `grep -a` the zip files but depending on the content of the file and your pattern, you might get false positives and/or false negatives.

Comment: Where would the first option unzip the files to?

Comment: `unzip -c` decompresses the file to stdout. It doesn't write the whole uncompressed file anywhere else.

Comment: +1 tks a lot it save my day . I juste add echo "$file";         unzip -c "$file" | grep -q "ORA-1680"; to know the file name + the result.

Comment: My version of `unzip` uses `-p` for streaming to pipe!

Comment: This works where all the single line commands returned "standard output", not a file name +1

Answer (score 26):

`zipgrep` takes a single file. To make it work across multiple files put it in a loop:

```
for i in *.zip
do
   zipgrep ORA-1680 "$i"
done
```

Comment: In one line that also print zip filename if there is a match: `for i in *.zip; do zipgrep TextToSearch $i && echo $i; done`

Answer (score 4):

The [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) filesystem presents a view of the filesystem where every archive file `/path/to/foo.zip` is accessible as a directory `~/.avfs/path/to/foo.zip#`. It's a [FUSE](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) filesystem, which you can install on Solaris. AVFS provides read-only access to most common archive file formats.

```
mountavfs
for z in ~/.avfs$PWD/*.zip; do
  find "$z#" -exec grep ORA-1680 {} +
done
fusermount -u ~/.avfs   # optional
```

Answer (score 4):

## Try ugrep

[ugrep](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep) recursively searches zip, gz, tar, tgz, bz2, lz4, zstd, pax, cpio, and other types of compressed files and archives with [option `-z`](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep#archives).