# Zgrep stop after first match when arguments are passed from xargs

Tags: bash, find, grep, xargs

I'm using this command to find patterns in zip files (similar to the one) suggested here 
https://superuser.com/questions/144926/unix-grep-for-a-string-within-all-gzip-files-in-all-subdirectories

```
find . -regex ".*/.*zip" | xargs zgrep -m 1 -E "PATTERN"
```

Grepping still continues after first match. Probably `find`/`xargs` is the culprit. How to stop finding after `grep` finds first match?

P.S. [How to stop the find command after first match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62880/how-to-stop-the-find-command-after-first-match) won't work because `find` needs to be stopped after a match that succeeds grep and not just the first match of find.

Comment: do you mean first match in the entire set of files, or stop after the first match in each file?

Comment: @CraigSanders My zips contain the pattern only once. I want the only zip that contains the pattern.

Comment: Related: [Searching for a string on multiple zip files.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18552/searching-for-a-string-on-multiple-zip-files/18572#18572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things:

- `zgrep` is to look into `.z` or `.gz` compressed files, not files inside compressed `zip` archives.

  There's a (broken) `zipgrep` script sometimes bundled with `unzip`, to look into `zip` archives, but what it does is run `egrep` on each member of the archive (so with `-m1` each `egrep` would report the first match for each file).

  `zgrep`, similarly is a script that comes with `gzip` that feeds the output of `gzip -cdfq` to `grep` for each file. `gzip -d` can uncompress `zip` files, but only does so for the first member of the archive and only if it is compressed (in `zip` files, not all members are necessarily compressed, especially small ones).
- `xargs` runs as few commands as necessary but it may still run several if the list of files is big.

Here, your best bet is probably to implement `zipgrep` by hand (here with GNU tools):

```
find . -name '*.zip' -type f -exec sh -c '
    unzip -Z1 "$1" |
      while IFS= read -r file; do
        unzip -p "$1" "$file" | grep --label="$1//$file" -Hm1 -- "$0" && exit
      done' PATTERN {} \; -quit
```

That runs one shell per file, but so would `zipgrep` and `zipgrep` runs many more commands.

It can fail if archive members have names that contain wildcard characters (`*`, `[`, `?`) or other characters like ASCII characters 0x1 to 0x1f and various other ones, but that's mostly due to bugs and limitations in `unzip`, and that's not as bad as when using `zipgrep`.

Comment: But `zgrep` can actually search through `zip` archives, at least it does on my system. Is it somehow a bad idea nevertheless?

Comment: @terdon, that's only for `zip` files that contain only one compressed file. See the _Files  created  by  zip  can  be uncompressed by gzip only if they have a single member compressed with the 'deflation' method. This feature is only intended to help conversion of
       tar.zip files to the tar.gz format._ in `gzip` man page.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
find . -iname '*.zip' -print0 | xargs -0r zgrep -l -E 'PATTERN'
```

I've used `-iname` rather than `-regex` - it works as well for this and is, IMO, less confusing than `find`'s weird regex handling.  `-print0` and `xargs -0` are used so that any filenames with spaces or shell metacharacters in them will be handled correctly.

`grep`'s `-l` option is documented in the man page:

```
   -l, --files-with-matches
          Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print the name of each input
          file from which output would normally have  been  printed.   The
          scanning  will  stop  on  the  first match.
```

The first match mentioned is per file, so if multiple files match, they will all be printed.  note that this means that grep will continue searching the other files, even after it has found one match.

If you want it to stop after the very first match, you could use `grep`'s `--line-buffered` option and pipe grep's output into `head -1`.  When the first match is printed, `head` will print it and terminate, `grep` will no longer have a stdout so it will terminate, and `find` will follow.

```
find . -iname '*.zip' -print0 | xargs -0r zgrep --line-buffered -l -E 'PATTERN' | head -1
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to avoid `grep will continue searching the other files, even after it has found one match`

Comment: AFAIK, grep doesn't have any option to do that...but you might be able to do it with grep's `--line-buffered` option and pipe grep into `head -1`.  i'll add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`grep`'s (or `zgrep`'s) `-m` option will cause it to stop reading the **current file** on the first match:

```
   -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
          Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.
```

That will not stop it from searching the *next* file. For example:

```
$ echo "hello" > foo
$ echo "hello" > bar
$ grep -m 1 hello foo bar
foo:hello
bar:hello
```

So, the issue is not `xargs` but the fact that you are grepping multiple files. In order to have `grep` (or `zgrep`) stop after the first matching *file*, you would have to run a little loop like @Stephane has suggested. Or, something like this with bash :

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/*.zip; do
  zgrep -l pattern "$i" && break; 
done
```

Or, for zip archives that [contain multiple files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91344/zgrep-stop-after-first-match-when-arguments-are-passed-from-xargs#comment137810_91410) (thanks @Stephane):

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/*.zip; do
  if unzip -p "$i" | grep -q hello; then 
    echo "$i" && break;
  fi;
done
```

Comment: Note that `**/*.zip`, contrary to the `find` counterpart would not include dot-files or dot-dirs, also, expansions may start with `-` (while with `find .` they start with `./`), so you may want to add a `--`. Also, contrary to zsh or ksh93 where it copied that feature from, `bash`'s `**/` follows symlinks when descending the directory tree, so is to be used with care.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -m 1` lists the first match of every file.

There's an easy way of listing just the first match: pipe through `head -n 1`. The search will soon die of a [SIGPIPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPIPE#SIGPIPE).

```
find . -regex ".*/.*zip" -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep -E "PATTERN" | head -n 1
```