# Unzip: find a string and get inside filename

Tags: bash, zip

I have a list of zip files containing themselves multiple files.

Like this :

```
| archive-1.zip
    | file1.xml
    | file2.xml
    | file3.xml --> contains myStringToFind
    | file4.xml
| archive-2.zip
    | file1b.xml
    | file2b.xml
| archive-3.zip
    | file1c.xml
    | file2c.xml
```

My goal is to find a string across the files within those zip archives.
What I've achived so far is that :

```
for i in archive*.zip;do unzip -c "$i" 2>/dev/null|grep -l myStringToFind;
if test $? -eq 0; then echo $i;fi;
done|grep archive
```

Output: `archive-1.zip`
.With this I'm able to find the archive containing my string.

The next step is to find the name of the file within the archive, but I'm unable to find a way to do this.
My expected output would be `archive-1.zip file3.xml`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use `zipgrep` for `zip` archives and `zgrep` for `gz` archives easily. Please have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18557/254422

Comment: Thank you @binarysta! I was able to do the thing I wanted with zipgrep

Comment: @binarysta could you flesh that out into an answer so the question can be marked as answered?

Comment: @binarysta perfect, thanks!