# Find recursively all archive files of diverse archive formats and search them for file name patterns

Tags: find, tar, zip, 7z, rar

At best I would like to have a call like this:

```
$searchtool /path/to/search/ -contained-file-name "*vacation*jpg"
```

... so that this tool

- does a recursive scan of the given path
- takes all files with supported archive formats which should at least be the "most common" like zip, rar, 7z, tar.bz, tar.gz ...
- and scan the file list of the archive for the name pattern in question (here `*vacation*jpg`)

I'm aware of how to use the find tool, tar, unzip and alike. I could combine these with a shell script but I'm looking for a simple solution that might be a shell one-liner or a dedicated tool (hints to GUI tools are welcome but my solution must be command line based).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*(Adapted from [How do I recursively grep through compressed archives?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13749/how-do-i-recursively-grep-through-compressed-archives/13798#13798))*

Install [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/), a filesystem that provides transparent access inside archives. First run this command once to set up a view of your machine's filesystem in which you can access archives as if they were directories:

```
mountavfs
```

After this, if `/path/to/archive.zip` is a recognized archive, then `~/.avfs/path/to/archive.zip#` is a directory that appears to contain the contents of the archive.

```
find ~/.avfs"$PWD" \( -name '*.7z' -o -name '*.zip' -o -name '*.tar.gz' -o -name '*.tgz' \) \
     -exec sh -c '
                  find "$0#" -name "*vacation*.jpg"
                 ' {} 'Test::Version' \;
```

Explanations:

- Mount the AVFS filesystem.
- Look for archive files in `~/.avfs$PWD`, which is the AVFS view of the current directory.
- For each archive, execute the specified shell snippet (with `$0` = archive name and `$1` = pattern to search).
- `$0#` is the directory view of the archive `$0`.
- `{\}` rather than `{}` is needed in case the outer `find` substitutes `{}` inside `-exec ;` arguments (some do it, some don't).

Or in zsh ≥4.3:

```
mountavfs
ls -l ~/.avfs$PWD/**/*.(7z|tgz|tar.gz|zip)(e\''
     reply=($REPLY\#/**/*vacation*.jpg(.N))
'\')
```

Explanations:

- `~/.avfs$PWD/**/*.(7z|tgz|tar.gz|zip)` matches archives in the AVFS view of the current directory and its subdirectories.
- `PATTERN(e\''CODE'\')` applies CODE to each match of PATTERN. The name of the matched file is in `$REPLY`. Setting the `reply` array turns the match into a list of names.
- `$REPLY\#` is the directory view of the archive.
- `$REPLY\#/**/*vacation*.jpg` matches `*vacation*.jpg` files in the archive.
- The `N` glob qualifier makes the pattern expand to an empty list if there is no match.

Answer (score 13):

If you want something simpler that the AVFS solution, I wrote a Python script to do it called [arkfind](https://github.com/detly/arkfind). You can actually just do

```
$ arkfind /path/to/search/ -g "*vacation*jpg"
```

It'll do this recursively, so you can look at archives inside archives to an arbitrary depth.

Comment: Thanks, nice contribution! Especially if AVFS is no option.

Comment: It would be great if it supports jar files.

Comment: @Chemik - [noted](https://github.com/detly/arkfind/issues/4)! I'll do a bit more work on it this weekend :) JAR shouldn't be too hard, I believe it's really just a zip file to the outside world.

Comment: @Chemik - I just tried it, and it should support JAR files in its current form anyway. Can you test it out, and if it doesn't work as you expect, file a bug on the Github page? (I did just fix a bug, so be sure to update your copy.)

Comment: Yes I see now, it works. You can add "JAR files" to README :)

Comment: It works for me when passing an archive as argument, but not a directory: `IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '.'`

Comment: @golimar That's weird, I thought I tested it on directories. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 3):

My **usual** solution:

```
find -iname '*.zip' -exec unzip -l {} \; 2>/dev/null | grep '\.zip\|DESIRED_FILE_TO_SEARCH'
```

Example:

```
find -iname '*.zip' -exec unzip -l {} \; 2>/dev/null | grep '\.zip\|characterize.txt'
```

Resuls are like:

```
foozip1.zip:
foozip2.zip:
foozip3.zip:
    DESIRED_FILE_TO_SEARCH
foozip4.zip:
...
```

If you want only the zip file with **hits** on it:

```
find -iname '*.zip' -exec unzip -l {} \; 2>/dev/null | grep '\.zip\|FILENAME' | grep -B1 'FILENAME'
```

**FILENAME** here is used twice, so you can use a variable.

With find you might use **PATH/TO/SEARCH**

Answer (score 3):

Another solution that works is `zgrep`

```
zgrep -r filename *.zip
```

Comment: What implementation of `zgrep` is that? That doesn't work with the one shipped with GNU `gzip` (`/bin/zgrep: -r: option not supported`, `zgrep (gzip) 1.6`)

Answer (score 3):

IMHO user-friendliness should be a thing in bash as well :

```
 while read -r zip_file ; do echo "$zip_file" ; unzip -l "$zip_file" | \
 grep -i --color=always -R "$to_srch"; \
 done < <(find . \( -name '*.7z' -o -name '*.zip' \)) | \
 less -R
```

and for tar ( this one is untested ... )

```
 while read -r tar_file ; do echo "$tar_file" ; tar -tf  "$tar_file" | \
 grep -i --color=always -R "$to_srch"; \
 done < <(find . \( -name '*.tar.gz' -o -name '*.tar' \)) | \
 less -R
```

Comment: What `unzip` implementation can deal with 7z or tar.gz files?

Comment: yeah that is a bug ... corrected ... one should definitely use the correct binaries for the correct file types ... I just aimed to demonstrate the one-liner .. jee this one almost will get to the state of being ready as how-to receipt ...

Answer (score 2):

`libarchive`'s `bsdtar` can handle most of those file formats, so you could do:

```
find . \( -name '*.zip' -o     \
          -name '*.tar' -o     \
          -name '*.tar.gz' -o  \
          -name '*.tar.bz2' -o \
          -name '*.tar.xz' -o  \
          -name '*.tgz' -o     \
          -name '*.tbz2' -o    \
          -name '*.7z' -o      \
          -name '*.iso' -o     \
          -name '*.cpio' -o    \
          -name '*.a' -o       \
          -name '*.ar' \)      \
       -type f                 \
       -exec bsdtar tf {} '*vacation*jpg' \; 2> /dev/null
```

Which you can simplify (and improve to match case-insensitively) with GNU `find` with:

```
find . -regextype egrep \
       -iregex '.*\.(zip|7z|iso|cpio|ar?|tar(|\.[gx]z|\.bz2)|tgz|tbz2)' \
       -type f \
       -exec bsdtar tf {} '*vacation*jpg' \; 2> /dev/null
```

That doesn't print the path of the archive where those `*vacation*jpg` files are found though. To print that name you could replace the last line with:

```
-exec sh -ac '
   for ARCHIVE do
     bsdtar tf "$ARCHIVE" "*vacation*jpg" |
       awk '\''{print ENVIRON["ARCHIVE"] ": " $0}'\''
   done' sh {} + 2> /dev/null
```

which gives an output like:

```
./a.zip: foo/blah_vacation.jpg
./a.zip: bar/blih_vacation.jpg
./a.tar.gz: foo/blah_vacation.jpg
./a.tar.gz: bar/blih_vacation.jpg
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
for archive (**/*.(#i)(zip|7z|iso|cpio|a|ar|tar(|.gz|.xz|.bz2)|tgz|tbz2)(.ND)) {
  matches=("${(f@)$(bsdtar tf $archive '*vacation*jpg' 2> /dev/null)"})
  (($#matches)) && printf '%s\n' "$archive: "$^matches
}
```

Note that there are a number of other file formats that are just `zip` or `tgz` files in disguise like `.jar` or `.docx` files. You can add those to your `find`/`zsh` search pattern, `bsdtar` doesn't care about the extension (as in, it doesn't rely on the extension to determine the type of the file).

Note that `*vacation*.jpg` above is matched on the full archive member path, not just the file name, so it would match on `vacation.jpg` but also on `vacation/2014/file.jpg`.

To match on the filename only, one trick would be to use the *extract* mode, use `-s` (substitution) which uses regexps with a `p` flag to print the names of the matching files and then make sure no file is extracted, like:

```
bsdtar -'s|.*vacation[^/]*$||' -'s|.*||' -xf "$archive"
```

Note that it would output the list on stderr and append `>>` to every line. In any case, `bsdtar`, like most `tar` implementations may mangle the file names on display if they contain some characters like newline or backslash (rendered as `\n` or `\\`).