# Search for files with a specific size inside recursive zipped archives

Tags: bash, shell, gzip, zip

I have a folder with several files. These files are either `.xml` or `.zip` files.
These `.zip` files contain `.xml` and/or `.zip` files. These `.zip` contains also `.xml` or `.zip`, and so on... until we finally found `.xml` files.

In others words, I can have several "levels" of zip before finding my `.xml` files (cf. example below).

My requirement is to detect which **root** ZIP files contain at least one XML file that is bigger than 100Mb.
When a ZIP file is in such case, it should be moved to another directory (let say `~/big-files`).
Also, if a non zipped `.xml` file is bigger than 100Mb, then it should be moved to this directory.

For example:

```
foo1.xml
foo2.xml
baz.xml [MORE THAN 100Mb]
one.zip
  +- foo.xml
  +- bar.xml [MORE THAN 100Mb]
  +- foo.xml
two.zip
  +- foo.xml
  +- zip-inside1.zip
  |   +- bar.xml [MORE THAN 100Mb]
  +- foo.xml
three.zip
  +- foo.xml
  +- zip-inside2.zip
  |   +- zip-inside3.zip
  |       +- foo.xml
  |       +- bar.xml [MORE THAN 100Mb]
  +- foo.xml
four.zip
  +- foo.xml
  +- zip-inside1.zip
      +- foo.xml
```

In this example, *baz.xml*, *one.zip*, *two.zip* and *three.zip* should be moved to `~/big-files` as they host at least one XML file bigger than 100Mb, but not *four.zip*.

How can I achieve that in bash shell?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can.   Certainly `find` does not look inside zip files.   You will need to write a script to do this in a more powerful language (Python, Ruby, Perl, etc.)

Comment: @JamesYoungman - Find can look look into zip files using -exec unzip -l.

Comment: So you would need to use something like `-exec sh -c "unzip -l $@ ... | grep" xxx`.   That's a (small) shell script.

Answer (score 2):

First, install [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/), a filesystem that provides transparent access inside archives, and run the command `mountavfs`. See [How do I recursively grep through compressed archives?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13749/how-do-i-recursively-grep-through-compressed-archives/13798#13798) for background.

After this, if `/path/to/archive.zip` is a recognized archive, then `~/.avfs/path/to/archive.zip#` is a directory that appears to contain the contents of the archive.

Write an auxiliary script called `has_large_file_rec` that looks for a large XML file in the zip file passed as argument and calls itself recursively on every embedded zip file. This script produces some output if it finds a large XML file inside. The output is truncated for efficiency, since once we've found one large XML file we might as well stop searching.

```
#!/bin/sh
## auxiliary script has_large_file_rec
find "$1#" -name '*.zip' -type f -exec has_large_file_rec {} \; \
        -o -name '*.xml' -type f -size +1024k -print | head -n 1
```

At the top level, if you find a large file, move it to the big file directory.

```
find "~/.avfs$PWD" \
  -name '*.zip' -sh -c '
      a=$(has_large_file_rec "$0")
      if [ -n "$a" ]; then mv "$0" ~/big-files/; fi
                       ' {} \; -o \
  -name '*.xml' -type f -size +1024k -exec mv {} ~/big-files/ \;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `perl`.

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Archive::Extract;
use List::Util qw|first|;
use File::Copy qw|move|;
use File::Spec;
use File::Path qw|remove_tree|;

## Path to save 'xml' and 'zip' files.
my $big_files_dir = qq|$ENV{HOME}/big_files/|;

## Temp dir to extract files of 'zips'.
my $zips_path = qq|/tmp/zips$$/|;

## Size in bytes to check 'xml' files.
my $file_max_size_bytes = 100 * 1024 * 1024;

my (@zips_to_move, $orig_zip);

## Get files to process.
my @files = <*.xml *.zip>;                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

## From previous list, copy 'xml' files bigger than size limit.                                                                                                                                                                              
for my $file ( @files ) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        if ( substr( $file, -4 ) eq q|.xml| and -s $file > $file_max_size_bytes ) {                                                                                                                                                          
                move $file, $big_files_dir;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

## Process now 'zip' files. For each one remove temp dir to avoid mixing files                                                                                                                                                               
## from different 'zip' files.                                                                                                                                                                                                               
for ( grep { m/\.zip\Z/ } @files ) {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        remove_tree $zips_path;                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        $orig_zip = $_;                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        handle_zip_file( $orig_zip );                                                                                                                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

## Copy 'zip' files got until now.                                                                                                                                                                                                           
for my $zip_file ( @zips_to_move ) {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        move $zip_file, $big_files_dir;                                                                                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

## Traverse recursively each 'zip file. It will look for 'zip' file in the                                                                                                                                                                   
## subtree and will extract all 'xml' files to a temp dir. Base case is when                                                                                                                                                                 
## a 'zip' file only contains 'xml' files, then I will read size of all 'xmls'                                                                                                                                                               
## and will copy the 'zip' if at least one of them if bigger than the size limit.                                                                                                                                                            
## To avoid an infinite loop searching into 'zip' files, I delete them just after                                                                                                                                                            
## the extraction of its content.                                                                                                                                                                                                            
sub handle_zip_file {                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        my ($file) = @_;                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

        my $ae = Archive::Extract->new(                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                archive => $file,                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                type => q|zip|,                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

        $ae->extract(
                to => $zips_path,
        );

        ## Don't check fails. I don't worry about them, ¿perhaps should I?
        unlink( File::Spec->catfile( 
                                (File::Spec->splitpath( $zips_path ))[1], 
                                (File::Spec->splitpath( $file ))[2],
                        )
        );

        my $zip = first { substr( $_, -4 ) eq q|.zip| } <$zips_path/*>;
        if ( ! $zip ) {
                for my $f ( <$zips_path/*.xml> ) {
                        if ( substr( $f, -4 ) eq q|.xml| and -s $f > $file_max_size_bytes ) {
                                push @zips_to_move, $orig_zip;
                                last;
                        }
                }
                return;
        }

        handle_zip_file( $zip );
}
```

Some issues:

- `xml` files with same name in the subtree of a `zip` file will be overwritten when copied to the temp dir.
- This program extracts content of all zip files of the same tree and
  then checks for a `xml` bigger than 100MB. It would be faster to
  check each time I extract a zip file. It can be improved.
- It doesn't cache zip files processed more than once.
- `~/big_files` must exists and be writable.
- The script doesn't accept arguments. You must run it in the same
  directory as the `zip` and `xml` files.

It's not perfect as you can see in previous points but it worked in my test. I hope it can be useful for you.

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```