# Is it possible to view the list of file names of a zip file which is inside another zip file?

Tags: bash, command-line, zip

I know I can use `unzip -l file.zip` to view the file list of a zip file.

But a got a zip file inside another zip file. I tried `unzip -l file.zip/sub_file.zip`, but failed.

Is it possible to view the file list of the `sub_file.zip`  without extract it out?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `less` with [Wolfgang Friebel's `lesspipe` script](https://www.zeuthen.desy.de/~friebel/unix/lesspipe.html): `less file.zip:sub_file.zip`

Comment: Is this `:` symbol used to refer to zip file relationship only, or have other usages?

Comment: I got this: `zipinfo:  cannot find or open 2014-08-16.zip:info_2014-08-16.zip, 2014-08-16.zip:info_2014-08-16.zip.zip or 2014-08-16.zip:info_2014-08-16.zip.ZIP`

Comment: But I have this info_2014-08-16.zip file in the 2014-08-16.zip file. `[admin@cjxx-s1 platform]$ unzip -l 2014-08-16.zip 
Archive:  2014-08-16.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
  3145521  08-17-2014 00:47   info_2014-08-16.zip
  1047822  08-17-2014 00:47   pay_2014-08-16.zip
 46524282  08-17-2014 00:48   spend_2014-08-16.zip`

Comment: @Zen `:` is used to accede files in archives supported by `lesspipe`, recursively. If you get such errors, it seems that you are not using Wolfgang Friebel's `lesspipe`.

Comment: got it, it means I need to install a `lesspipe` program first, right? But that's not a good universal solution, I think.

Comment: @Zen `lesspipe` is so useful that it should be universal. I can't live without it: used with `less` (for which it has been written), it's the universal viewer in a text terminal.

Comment: I'm confused, `less` is an inside build program on Ubuntu, I can use it without installing anything, but is this `less` command the same thing with `lesspipe`? If they are the same thing, why my `less file.zip:sub_file.zip` doesn't work?

Comment: @Zen This is the same `less`: `lesspipe` is an input preprocessor, used with the `LESSOPEN` environment variable, e.g. `export LESSOPEN="|/path/to/lesspipe %s"`. See the `less(1)` man page for more information.

Comment: I was in the middle of writing an answer here, but... does this work *recursively*?  I guess it just creates as many temp files as it needs? I like this - I have `lesspipe` but I am not sure about Wolfgang... I need to check. In the meantime, screw my answer.

Comment: @mikeserv The [README](http://www-zeuthen.desy.de/~friebel/unix/less/README) file says that file extraction works up to a depth of 6. I suppose that this is sufficient in practice! Note that this also works with compressed files (`.gz`, etc.), with `.deb` files, and so on. Internally temp files (or pipes) are used, but this is transparent. If the `lesspipe` script doesn't contain the text "Wolfgang Friebel", you don't have the right one.

Answer (score 2):

`unzip -l file.zip/sub_file.zip` doesn't work because `file.zip` isn't a directory: it's a regular file that happens to be in an archive format. But you can create a directory that mirrors the content of the zip file, by mounting a filesystem that presents a view of the content of the zip file. There are several choices, pick whichever is easiest to install on your distribution:

- [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/)
- [fuse-zip](http://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/)
- [archivemount](http://www.cybernoia.de/software/archivemount/)

For example, with archivemount:

```
mkdir file.d
archivemount file.zip file.d
unzip -l file.d/sub_file.zip
fusermount -u file.d
```

or even

```
mkdir file.d sub_file.d
archivemount file.zip file.d
archivemount file.d/sub_file.zip sub_file.d
ls -lR sub_file.d
fusermount -u sub_file.d
fusermount -u file.d
```

See [Extract only a specific file from a zipped archive to a given directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14120/extract-only-a-specific-file-from-a-zipped-archive-to-a-given-directory/14125#14125), [How do I recursively grep through compressed archives?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13749/how-do-i-recursively-grep-through-compressed-archives) and [Search for files with a specific size inside recursive zipped archives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42468/search-for-files-with-a-specific-size-inside-recursive-zipped-archives) for examples of AVFS and fuse-zip in similar situations.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
$ unzip -l a.zip.zip
Archive:  a.zip.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      195  2014-08-18 09:38   a.zip
---------                     -------
      195                     1 file

$ unzip -l =(unzip -p a.zip.zip a.zip)
Archive:  /tmp/zsh0i0JyZ
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       55  2014-08-15 15:24   a
---------                     -------
       55                     1 file
```

`=(...)` is a third form of process substitution that  uses a temporary file instead of a pipe (`unzip` only works with  seekable files).